# Replacing strings and characters inside urls

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I'm trying to replace characters inside urls starting with a certain pattern and to add ".html" at the end. I'm using Sublime Text but can't make it work completely.

I would like to do 3 switches:

1. https://my.master.com to https__my.master.com
2. adding ".html" at the end of each url
3. replacing "/" inside these urls with "_"

Important: Only for urls starting with href="https://my.master.com/@

**Example:**

href="https://my.master.com/@top-com/d/my-zen/"

**Result I would like to get:**

href="https__my.master.com_@top-com_d_my-zen_.html"

**What I've tried so far:**

Inside Sublime Text, I've tried to put inside the find field:

```
href="https://my.master.com/@([^\"]+)
```

and inside the replace field:

```
href="https__my.master.com_@$1.html"
```

It works for 1) and 2) but not 3). I don't know how to also replace  "/" with "_"

**The output I get with my regex:**

https__my.master.com_@top-com/d/my-zen/.html

**It's not something for production**

I don't mind doing 2 find and replace in a row if it's easier for you to help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just curious, why do you need to make these replacements?

Comment: Is Notepad++ an option? I have a solution in one step but, unfortunatly, it doesn't work with Sublime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how many subdirs you might have, you can likely use some expressions similar to:

```
href="https:\/\/my\.master\.com\/@([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)\/"
href="https:\/\/my\.master\.com\/@([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)\/"
```

and replace those with some similar strings:

```
href="https:__my.master.com_@$1_$2_$3_.html"
href="https:__my.master.com_@$1_$2_$3_$4_.html"
```

a few times.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/17h0a8/1)

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/17h0a8/1). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/17h0a8/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

Answer (score 0):

If Notepad++ is an option for you, you can do the following that, unfortunatly, doesn't work with SublimeText.

This is working for any number of slashes in the URL.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:https|\G).*?\K:?/(")?`
- Replace with: `_(?1.html$1:)`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *UNCHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:         # non capture group
  https     # literally
 |          # OR
  \G        # restart from last match position
)           # end group
.*?         # 0 or more any character but newline, not greedy
\K          # forget all we have seen until this position
:?          # optional colon
/           # slash
(")?        # group 1, a double quote, optional
```

**Replacement:**

```
_           #  underscore
(?1         # if group 1  exists (i.e. there is a double quote)
    .html   # literally
    $1      # content of group 1
    :       # else
            # nothing
)           # endif
```

**Given:**

```
href="https://my.master.com/@top-com/d/my-zen/"
href="https://my.master.com/my-zen/"
href="https://my.master.com/@top-com/d/e/f/g/my-zen/"
```

**Result for given example:**

```
href="https__my.master.com_@top-com_d_my-zen_.html"
href="https__my.master.com_my-zen_.html"
href="https__my.master.com_@top-com_d_e_f_g_my-zen_.html"
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your long reply. I wish I had seen it before using Sublime Text. The community needs more guys like you! :)

Comment: @LeonardoDiaz: You're welcome. Be aware that other answer doesn't work for unknown number of slashes in the URL.